# mssql связанный сервер с firebird

Tags: sql-server

Хочу создать связанный сервер в mssql к firebird!!!

- установил ibprovider v5 (х64), прописал вкл. параметров:
  [image: use]
- установил lcpi ado.net data provider for ole db, в ssms показал провайдера:

[image: use]

- создаю связанный сервер, прописал вкл. параметров:
  [image: use]

Сервер создается успешно, но при попытки проверить соединения, выскакивает ошибка
[image: use]

Comment: видимо нужен провайдер x86

Comment: Устанавливал 32 провайдер, в ssms не отображался в поставщиках

Comment: Recommendations:

In case of 64-bit operating system, we strongly recommend that you install both 32-bit and 64-bit provider.
We do not recommend that you use IBProvider Lite when working with MSSQL.

Comment: https://www.ibprovider.com/eng/documentation/mssql_2012.html

Comment: Выполнял данный пункт, ставил 64 и 32, ошибка выходила так же, и версия не lite

Comment: значит надо обращаться в их поддержку

Answer (score 0):

Исправил ошибку. В строке поставщика (@provstr) нет необходимости указывать путь к dll

вместо команды

```
dbclient_library=D:\fbclient.dll
```

необходимо прописать команду

```
dbclient_type=fb.direct
```